# Volume of the Region bounded by $y = 2x^2 +2z^2$ and the plane $y=8$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d, volume

I have the find the volume of the region bounded by the paraboloid $y = 2x^2 +2z^2$ and the plane $y=8$. Is the volume (using triple integrals) just $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{2x^2+2z^2}^8dydzdx$$
I understand the bounds for y (from the paraboloid to the plane), but I don't understand what are the bounds for x and z.

Comment: Should the equation be $$\color{red}{\mathbf z} = 2x^2 +2y^2$$

Comment: @Sabyasachi I changed the bounds. It's a paraboloid extending from the y-axis.

Comment: Still shouldn't your equation have **all** co-ordinates in it?

Answer (score 1):

$y = 2x^2 +2z^2$ and the plane $y=8$ gives:

$8=2x^2 +2z^2$

$4=x^2 +z^2$

This is a circle and gives you limits for $x$ and $z$ obviously it will be polar coordinates problems in xz space.

Limits for y are solved because your surface is going from paraboloid to the $y=8$, so modify your integral bounds... to be something like: $x=rcos(\phi), z=rsin(\phi)$, $y=y$:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{2}dr\int_{2r^2}^8 rdy$$

projecting the section of paraboloid and $y=8$ you get xz projection which defines you x and z bounds.